# How to handle "Connection reset" error

Tags: java, sockets, serversocket

I'm trying to connect one Socket with one ServerSocket, but when de socket fails, the error "Connection reset" show up in the Server, how can I handle this?

Comment: Catch the exception that might get thrown at the server and handle it appropriately.

Comment: Which in turn means closing the socket and forgetting about that client.